# Consuming OData and create smart-graph in UI5

Tags: data-binding, odata, data-visualization, sapui5

I want to consume OData services and create a smart graph using opensap UI5.
I **can set the model** and **fetch data in a table** but for the same data I am **unable to create a Smart-graph.**

I am able to fetch data from the odata service and represent in a table, I want to represent same data in the smart-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with about question is that to create a smart-chat, we need to have annotations coming from our OData service that should tell how the smart chart is rendered. It's not possible to create smart charts with normal OData.

For further details refer this: 
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/12/10/an-ui5-smart-chart-app-based-on-actual-server-backed-by-cloud-foundry-on-sap-web-ide/